# Modify a plugin function output from another plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, filters, shortcode, plugin-types

I'm writing a plugin for a wordpress site using a page template using [WP Types plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/).

My plugin adds a shortcode tag.

Shortcode tags inside 'the_content' get processed without problem.

But this page template echoes `types_render_field(...)` WP Types function which gets and returns content containing shortcode tags retrieved from the database using `get_post_custom($postid)` wordpress core function call.

I want to process these shortcode tags without modifying the template or WP Types plugin, just using my plugin code.

Is that possible?

Comment: If [this](http://wp-types.com/) is the plugin, it is commercial. The code is not easy to come by. Ask their support about this.

Comment: I don't know if it's commercial or not (it's not my deployment), but the code is available for download in wordpress.org: http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/types.1.5.3.zip

Comment: What is the code for `types_render_field`?

Comment: it's on file types/embedded/frontend.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will never understand the point of these wildly complicated "helper" wrapper/plugins... but that aside...

The plugin provides a lot of filters that might help you out. I think that the [`types_view`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/types/trunk/embedded/frontend.php#L328) filter might be what you want. Something like this is a plugin file or your theme `functions.php` might do it:

```
add_filter('types_view','do_shortcode');
```

I do not use that plugin, have never used that plugin, and I am guessing-- a lot-- but I hope that helps.

Comment: I still had to unescape and reformat the arguments passed to the shortcode handler function, (I got something like `array([0]=>'\\'fieldname\\'='\\'Title\\', ...)` instead of `array('fieldname'=>'Title', ...))`) but it worked. Thank you so much: WP Types is massive and way too complex (I also don't understand where's the benefit: you can probably achieve more or less the same functionality on this site without using it) and this problem was driving me crazy ^^'